# CakePHP3 CRUD API and API Routing

Tags: crud, cakephp-3.x

I am using the Friends of Cake CRUD plugin for my back-end API. I am also using API prefixes for my routes:

```
Router::prefix('Api', function ($routes) {
    $routes->extensions(['json', 'xml', 'ajax']);
    $routes->resources('Messages');
    $routes->resources('ReportedListings');
    $routes->fallbacks('InflectedRoute');
});
```

So far so good. My controller is as follows:

```
namespace App\Controller\Api;

use App\Controller\AppController;
use Cake\Event\Event;
use Cake\Core\Exception\Exception;

class MessagesController extends AppController {

    use \Crud\Controller\ControllerTrait;

    public function initialize() {  
        parent::initialize();      
        $this->loadComponent(
            'Crud.Crud', [
                'actions' => [
                    'Crud.Add',
                    'update' => ['className' => 'Crud.Edit']
                ],
                'listeners' => ['Crud.Api'],
            ]
            ,'RequestHandler'
        );     
        $this->Crud->config(['listeners.api.exceptionRenderer' => 'App\Error\ExceptionRenderer']);
        $this->Crud->addListener('relatedModels', 'Crud.RelatedModels');
    }

    public function beforeFilter(Event $event){
        parent::beforeFilter($event);      
    }

    public function add() {      
        return $this->Crud->execute();
    }
```

When I make a call as follows:

[POST] /api/messages.json

I get an error:

```
Action MessagesController::index() could not be found, or is not accessible.
```

I instead use:

[POST] /messages.json

I don't get the error and I can add a message. So the question is why with my api prefix routing does the CRUD look for index and how can I avoid this behavior?

Comment: Is it just a case of capitalised  "Api" instead of "api" in your Router::prefix?

Comment: You're not connecting any resource routes in your api prefix scope, only the standard fallback routes.

Comment: @ndm see my updated resources routes, now messages.json works but reportedListings.json is still looking for the index action?

Comment: You're probably not using inflected routes as defaults, but dashed routes, ie it should be `reported-listings.json`.

Comment: @ndm even when posting to /api/reported-listings.json it is looking for the index method. If I add the index method I don't get the error. There is without a doubt an issue here more than mis-configuration

Comment: Check `bin/cake routes` to see what routes exactly are connected.

Comment: @ndm this is my routes file: https://gist.github.com/spacebiscuit/5b9f07215523728cf65dad631ae17c88

Comment: I have tried creating a test FooBars controller to rule out any previous routes which might be causing the issue. /api/foo-bars.json [POST] .... same error for missing index action. Either my routes.php is screwed up or I have uncovered a bug when controller is multi-word and prefix routing is used

Comment: Does `Foobars` (single word) work? And again, please check `bin/cake routes` to see what routes exactly are created/connected from your code.

Comment: @ndm yes Foobars single word works fine, no errors when I post to api/foobars.json. There is a disconnect between the CRUD plugin and multi-word controller routes

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue:

```
Router::prefix('Api', function ($routes) {
     ....
}
```

The 'Api' should be lowercase!

```
Router::prefix('api', function ($routes) {
     ....
}
```

Comment: That's pretty weird, `Router::prefix()` sends the name through `Inflector::underscore()`, which would/should make it lowercase anyways.